# How to convert YUV plane to cv:: Mat object in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, mat, yuv

Converting YUVI420 plane to `OpenCV Mat`. I have three `uint8_t *` pointers yPlane, uPlane and vPlane how can I create a Mat object from these pointers?

```
+(UIImage *) i420ToRGB:(const uint8_t *) yPlane uPlane:(const uint8_t *) uPlane vPlane:(const uint8_t *) vPlane width:(uint)width height:(uint) height
{

    cv::Mat yuvMat;
    int rows = (int)(height * 3/2);
    yuvMat =cv::Mat(rows, int(width), CV_8UC1, yPlane,0)//Don't know how to do that



}
```